# thread wait for the connection to redis when use brpop/blpop

Tags: java, multithreading, redis, client, redis-cluster

Several threads are running with brpop involved, but it seems that each thread is waiting for another blocked thread's connection to redis(as the queue brpop operator on is mostly empty).
I use `StringRedisTemplate` to connect and I want to know how can each thread using its own connection to redis and not affect each other.